# Can I wire DSL connection through ethernet?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I have BT Broadband, and my master socket(the one with 2 sections) is in a bad place.
In my home, there is internal ethernet wiring(wires that go through the walls and come out through ethernet sockets).

Can I wire my dsl(the broadband cable from the master socket) through the ethernet so I can put my BT Home Hub somewhere else?

(Sorry if it is unclear, it's hard to explain.)

Comment: Theoretically it is possible - but the telephone part of the connection normally requires a filter. Provided you take that into account you can use Cat5 to run the DSL connection to another point. See [Hack your House: Run both ethernet and phone over existing Cat-5 cable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Hack-your-House-Run-both-ethernet-and-phone-over-/)

Answer (score 0):

If you make up a patch cable with RJ45 terminators and the center pins only connected you can easily hook it up. You need to ensure the other end of the ethernet run is DISCONNECTED first, you dont want line voltage from the exchange running into your switch.

As above, if your line is ADSL you want at least CAT4 cabling in the walls and if you have VDSL(Openreach fibre) then you must have at least CAT5e. Additionally if there are problems BT will make you move it back before troubleshooting.

Note: if cabling is poor DLM will quickly reduce your speed for 24hrs, so if you see that you'll know why.